# Slide in Menu for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'm trying to create a slide in menu that comes in from the left but I've done something and its coming in onto the right instead. I've programmatically done this not used storyboards as most of the time the constraints messes up.

for example heres a screenshot (probably something I've done): 
[Slide Menu - Gone Wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSr6H.png)

```
import UIKit

class SideInMenu: NSObject {

    let blackView = UIView()

    let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        return cv
    }()

    @objc func showSlideMenu() {
        //Show slide in menu Here

        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)

            blackView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target:
                self, action: #selector(handleDismiss)))

            window.addSubview(blackView)
            window.addSubview(collectionView)

            let width: CGFloat = 194
            let x = window.frame.width - width
            collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(x, 0, width, window.frame.height)
            //collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(x, 0, width, window.frame.height)

            blackView.frame = window.frame
            blackView.alpha = 0

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping:
                1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut,
                animations: {
                self.blackView.alpha = 1

                self.collectionView.frame = self.CGRectMake(width, 0, self.collectionView.frame.width, self.collectionView.frame.height)

            }, completion: nil)

        }
    }

    @objc func handleDismiss() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.blackView.alpha = 0
            if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
                self.collectionView.frame = self.CGRectMake(window.frame.width, 0, self.collectionView.frame.width, self.collectionView.frame.height)
            }
        }

    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func CGRectMake(_ x: CGFloat, _ y: CGFloat, _ width: CGFloat, _ height: CGFloat) -> CGRect {return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
    }
}
```

Comment: You really should be using constraints instead of explicitly defining frames. You can animate constraint changes if that's why you chose not to use them here.

Comment: Would it be better to animate the constraints instead of doing it the way i done it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always remember that 0, 0 for x and y is always the top left of the screen and if the width and height is 20, 20, it will go from the top left, right 20px across and down 20px. The first thing you have to do inside you `viewDidLoad` is to set the collectionViews initial frame, which is off screen like this. **DON'T FORGET MINUS WIDTH**:

```
self.collectionView.frame = self.CGRectMake(-width, 0, self.collectionView.frame.width, self.collectionView.frame.height)
```

Animate it in from the left like so:

```
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping:
            1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut,
            animations: {
            self.blackView.alpha = 1

            self.collectionView.frame = self.CGRectMake(0, 0, self.collectionView.frame.width, self.collectionView.frame.height)

        }, completion: nil)
```

Dismiss with:

```
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping:
            1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut,
            animations: {
            self.blackView.alpha = 1

            self.collectionView.frame = self.CGRectMake(-width, 0, self.collectionView.frame.width, self.collectionView.frame.height)

        }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I'm getting errors implementing the -width one and getting errors whilst its in the ViewDidLoad part

Comment: @RyanCouch Awesome man. Glad to help. I'd appreciate it if you voted it as the answer if it helped you out. Let me know if you have any more issues